# What are the consequences of having a work and personal iPhone with the same Apple ID?

Tags: iphone

I'm considering having both a work and personal iPhone.

The phone numbers will be different, but I'd like to use the same Apple ID for convenience.

But I'm concerned about possible cross-pollination. Presumably text messages will be separate, but things like apps and photographs will be the shared. Perhaps iMessage texts too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same Apple ID and as you wrote, apps, music, books and so on are shared between devices.

Regarding Photos, you can turn on/off syncronization (Settings -> [your name] -> iCloud -> Photos, then turn on/off iCloud Photo Sharing)

Regarding iMessage you can turn on and/or off this feature from your phone (Settings -> Messages)

Answer (score 2):

> But I'm concerned about possible cross-pollination.

Correct.

You either have to live with the fact that things like the Keychain (usernames/passwords/certificates) get shared between your work and personal device, or you make the decision to not sync them, losing that convenience factor.